# PHP Scrape and download files from urls with interval

Tags: php, download, set, bigdata

I've build a scraper to get some data from another website. The scraper runs currently at the command line in a screen so the process is never stopping. Between each request I've set an interval to keep things calm. In one scrape it's possible there are coming 100 files along with which needs to be download. Also this process haves an interval after every download.

Now I want to add the functionality in the back-end to scrape on the fly. Everything works fine, I get the first data set which only has 2 requests. Within this data returned I've an array with files need to be download (can be 10 can be +100).. I would like to create something the user can see realtime how far the download process is.

The thing I am facing, when the scraper has 2 jobs to do in a browser window with up to +20 downloads including intervals to keep things clam down it will take too much time. I am thinking about to save the files needed to be download into a database table and handle this part of the data process by another shell script (screen) or cronjob.

I am wondering about if my thoughts are in the good way, overkilled or there are some better examples to handle these kind of processes.

Thanks for any advice.

p.s. I am developing in PHP

Comment: I don't really need to try, I know it will work but my question is if the way to handle these things in this way are wise or I should handle this in another way

Answer (score 0):

If you think that is overkill, you can run the script and waiting that task is finished before run again.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to implement a [message queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue) where http request handler (front controller?) emit a message to fetch a page, and one or more workers do the job, optionally emitting more messages to the queue to download files.

There are plenty of MQ brokers, but you can implement your own with database as a queue storage.

Comment: Coo, I guess this the logic is in the same way as my mind ;) Thank you

Comment: Glad to know it helped. As a side note, you may like http://supervisord.org/ to "demonise"  your worker(s) instead of keep them running in detached screen session.